# Connection with Python to Webdav

Tags: python, webdav

I am trying to upload a file in a webdav server via Python, using webdavclient. I am using this script which is quite straightforward. I download the library both with Python 2 & 3.

```
import webdav.client as wc

options = {'webdav_hostname': "https://xxxxxx",
           'webdav_login': "xxx",
            'webdav_password': "xxx"
        }

client = wc.Client(options)
client.upload_sync(remote_path="/storage/test_dir/testfile.txt",
                   local_path="/home/ubuntu/testfile.txt")
```

I constantly get this error:

```
    import webdav.client as wc
ImportError: No module named client
```

Although

```
:~ nasiantalla$ pip install webdavclient
Requirement already satisfied: webdavclient in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from webdavclient)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from webdavclient)
Requirement already satisfied: pycurl in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from webdavclient)

~ nasiantalla$ pip3 install webdavclient
Requirement already satisfied: webdavclient in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pycurl in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from webdavclient)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from webdavclient)
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from webdavclient)
```

Has anyone used this before or had any similar issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

installation

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev python-pycurl
$ sudo easy_install webdavclient
```

update

```
$ sudo pip install -U webdavclient
```

Comment: you using ide or? where you runnning  your code?because if you using ide you need set correct interpereter from ide

Comment: still didn't work.. I was running from the server and the IDE, setting up all versions of Python. At the end I installed easywebdav and used this library.

Comment: i am using pycharm.i just installed webdav from paycharm->settings->project interpereter->avilable packages.all works

Comment: I tried both from PyCharm & with the Terminal and nothing worked for me..

Comment: from pycharm installation you get error??or succesfully installed?

Comment: successfully installed both in Pycharm and via Terminal.. Really not sure what is the issue. I tried in another server and it worked  and in my personal it still doesn't work. The only difference with the other server is that it had Python3 predefault. So I am not sure if this plays some role..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

> from webdav3.client import Client
>
> options = {'webdav_hostname': "https://xxxxxx",
>              'webdav_login': "xxx",
>               'webdav_password': "xxx"
>           }
>
> client = Client(options)